# How to implement search on encrypted database fields

Tags: php, mysql, search, encryption

Iam Using PHP & MySql for my web application. I have a requirement where I need to encrypt user specific information, say name & email_id.

```
$name = "Kevin John";
$encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
$secretHash = "25c6c7ff35b8879b151f2136cd13574";
$enc_name = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash);
```

Iam storing this encrypted name in my database. But the real problem is that I need to search the users based on their name.For example:-

```
$qry = "select * from users where name like %john%";
```

Any suggestion appreciated

Comment: i can remember this question is asked before in within the last 2 or 3 monthes. i will try to find it again.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you for your valuable time. Kindly note that I need to implement search using LIKE operator (%name%)

Comment: @HeraldCharley It is not suggested to encrypt the data that you want implement search on. I'm missing the context. Why do you want to encrypt the name?

Comment: @new_user I have a table where I store user specific information like name, email, dob. For security purposes my client doesnot want to store that information as just plain text and want to encrypt that data. But my web application has a search functionality(autosuggest) which searches the database with name as query parameter. Any possible solutions ?????

Comment: In that case I would suggest you to encrypt everything but name in that user info table.
If that is not possible. a possible solution is to query for all data and write for stringContains logic on the app layer.

Comment: @new_user I will have to encrypt all fields so first solution is not possible.
second solution will also not work because 

`Encrypted: HzEUR7ALKbAkvmQblWO40g== 
 Decrypted: Kevin John 
 Encrypted: TzieRuBGXP+bbUfkRN5RFQ== 
 Decrypted: John`

when I search for **john** encrypted string wont match because ** Kevin John** and **John** are encrypted in different format

Comment: i couldn't find the question.. but what you can do is making a encrypted word list table which you connect with the real table..  this is the most common way to implement this if you understand what i mean

Comment: @RaymondNijland in that case security is compromised, right?

Comment: not if you keep the data in the word list also encrypted.. So basically you are querying something like this... `SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN encrypted_users ON users.id = encrypted_users.user_id WHERE encrypted_users.username = '<john_encryped_string>'`

Comment: @RaymondNijland But how can I query **john** from **Kevin john**

`encrypted <Kevin John> = HzEUR7ALKbAkvmQblWO40g`
`encrypted <John> = TzieRuBGXP+bbUfkRN5RFQ`

So I wont be able to write a query like
`select * from users where name like %john%`

Comment: you need to separate the real user names in separated words for "Kevin John" as "Kevin" and "John", or even on a single digit and write a custom query i have shown then you can find word parts with encryption.. Then you can query ... `SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN encrypted_users ON users.id = encrypted_users.user_id WHERE encrypted_users.username = 'TzieRuBGXP+bbUfkRN5RFQ' ` ... The problem is you can't really implement `LIKE` operator with this unless you going for a one digit approach but then you need to also store some kind of position in the table so you can check if the digits..

Comment: .. are one word by checking data islands.. iám not going to provide a answer about this one because it can be a couple of hours work and testing..

Answer (score 1):

You may have several options, some easy some not

- search / key fields are usually stored unencrypted to overcome this problem (you don't want this apparently)
- as already suggested - scanning the whole table, decrypting every record would work, but may not be feasible

  - you may use static IV achieving deterministic encrytion, encrypt the searched term and search already encrypted value. Knowing that static IV is lowering (and sometimes breaking) the security level
  - you may have a look at [homomorphic encrytion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) specifically designed for operations over encrypted data, but without knowing what are you doing that may be very steep and error prone path to implement own crypto (not recommended even for seasoned professionals). I did not dare to go through this door yet.
  - you may store cryptographic hashes (e. g. sha256) of the indexed values (maybe along encrypted values) . Then you could just search for a hashed search term without being able to recoved original value

Answer (score 1):

Use AES Encryption & Decryption in SQL for implementing search on encrypted DB fields. syntax:-

---

> AES_ENCRYPT('Text_to_encrypt', 'secret_key')
>
> AES_DECRYPT('Text_to_decrypt', 'secret_key')

---

- First encrypt & store the data in DB using AES Encryption in sql

  `INSERT INTO User (fname,email,mobile) VALUES 
  (AES_ENCRYPT('Arun gopan', 'Qwfe345dgfdg'), AES_ENCRYPT('arun123@fa.com', 'Qwfe345dgfdg'),'9658475577');`

---

- Now you can query the DB using AES DECRYPT in sql for performing search operations.

  `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(fname,'Qwfe345dgfdg'), AES_DECRYPT(email,'Qwfe345dgfdg')
  FROM User
  WHERE AES_DECRYPT(fname,'Qwfe345dgfdg') LIKE '%Arun%';`

Answer (score 0):

It is not suggested to encrypt the data that you want to search on.

- you can either choose not to encrypt the field that you want to search on.
- or you can fetch all the data, decrypt and search if the row contains what you want on the app layer(I would not suggest this approach).

  ```
  // Pseudocode
  $searchTerm = 'john';
  $allNamesQuery = 'select * from users'; 
  $allNamesData = execQuery($allNamesQuery);
  $suggestions = [];
  foreach($allNamesData as $row){
      $row = decryptNameFromRow($row);
      if(contains($row['name'], $searchTerm))
         array_push($suggestions, $row);
  }
  print_r($suggestions);
  ```

  Please suggest if there are any alternatives.

Comment: what if you have miliions or even billions of records?

Comment: @RaymondNijland In my case I have 2 million record